# How did the English word inveigle evolve from the Latin aboculus?

Tags: english, etymology, latin, sound-change

***[inveigle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inveigle#English)***

> Early corruption of French **aveugler** (“to blind, to delude”),
>
> from **aveugle** (“blind”),
>
> from the Old French **avugle** (“without eyes”),
>
> from Latin **ab** + **oculus** (“eye”).
>
> The in- might be from other a-/en- variations found in Middle English, which was then latinised into in-.

The sound change from Latin **aboculus** to Old French **avugle** is difficult for me to deduce, so I wonder whether it is regular and is there any other example like this?

Comment: Are you talking about *b->v and/or *c->g? I know nothing about Romance languages, but intervocalic lenition is a very common process so these changes seem unsurprising.

Comment: The c->g is easily explained by the loss of the first /u/ in oculus, leaving /-okl-/; the proximity of the voiced /l/ would normally voice the /k/ to /g/. Like b->v intervocalically, this is unsurprising.

Comment: @jlawler, Hi! Thank you for your answer, I still wonder the change from L. /o/ to OF. /u/, is this conditional or non-conditional?

Comment: Vowels vary. A ***lot***. Most etymologies rely on consonants, unless there's a demonstrated vowel relation like Grimm's Law or Umlaut. A change from [o] in one language to [u] in a successor, with this many syllables reforming around it, over the course of a millennium, is not surprising and in fact is rather conservative. Certainly it needs no special explanation.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aveugle (scroll down to EÉTYMOL. ET HIST.)

Comment: Le Petit Robert (an iPad app) also gives the same 11th century form, avogle.

Comment: That particular vowel change is common in French. Consider Fr. _lieu_ < L. _locu(s)_, Fr. _seul_ < L. _solu(s)_, _feu_ < _focu(s)_, _heure_ < _hora_. Having said that, there are plenty of examples where Latin _o_ developed differently in French, and where other vowels developed into _eu_.

Answer (score 3):

**aboculus** to **aveugle** is totally regular and not very complicated development (i.e. can be explained by three or four processes that do not intertwine)

> 1) lenition of obstruents intervocallically gives you **b>v** and
>   **k>g**
>
> 2) post-accentual vowels being elided results for both **u>0**
>
> 3) in a closed syllable, short stressed **o>oe** (today spelt ; but this did not go through /u/)

All these changes occur in myriad other examples (sudor > sueur; opera > oeuvre, etc.)

The rendition **avugle** may be just freak of transcription or it might be dialectal (in some dialects, even accented short **o>u**, which was typically reserved only for the unaccented one) and the  grapheme might represent /u/ sound, not /y/.

Answer (score 1):

French vocabulary can be roughly divided into 3 groups:

1. Native French words which can be traced back to Vulgar Latin. These
   words usually have the largest amount of phonetical changes (as they
   are most ancient): *oculus > œil*.
2. Early loanwords from Latin. These words aren't traceable to Vulgar
   Latin, they were reborrowed to French from Medieval Latin, two
   already coexisting languages. These words have fewer phonetical
   changes than the first group. I think this is the case with
   *aboculus* > *avugle* (but I'm not entirely sure).
3. Late loanwords from Latin. This group of words underwent almost zero
   phonetical changes. This is the case with, for example, *ocularis* > *oculaire*.

Answer (score -5):

It didn't.

"veigle" means tool : handle.

Something you can handle as to make it a tool for a certain (personal) aim or purpose. Therefore

{ in+veigle } yields a direct meaning of: to [ utilize something : someone ] in its original sense.

Comment: intentionally voting merely to reduce or inflate another user's reputation is considered abuse.